# Expectation of an Itô integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I'm interested in computing the following expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[W_T\cdot\int_0^T f(s)\mathrm{d}W_s\right].$$
Here $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard $\mathbb{R}$-valued Brownian motion and $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$-function. Does someone know how to compute this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this from one of the actuarial exams?

Comment: I don't know - for me it's just one step in a proof for an exercise in financial mathematics.

Comment: @Misakov - Way too difficult for actuarial exams. I've tutored exam MFE material for at least 2-3 years now.

Comment: @Clarinetist I see. I'm actually preparing for July's MFE. I know how to solve the problems but I'm really confused about the background theory of all these stochastic calculus.

Comment: This has been asked very recently. The simplest answer uses Itô's isometry, thus $$\mathbb{E}\left[W_T\cdot\int_{0}^{T} f(s)\cdot\mathrm{d}W_s\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T}1\cdot\mathrm{d}W_s \cdot \int_{0}^{T}f(s)\cdot\mathrm{d}W_s\right]=\int_{0}^{T}1\cdot f(s)\,\mathrm ds.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also studying a course where things like this appear, so I'll present an attempt but corrections are welcome. I know stochastic calculus doesn't always play by the rules.

I get that: $$\mathbb{E}[W_T \cdot \int_0^Tf(s)dW_s] = \int_0^Tf(s)ds$$

If $\mathbf{P} = \{t_0 = 0, t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n = T\} $ is a tagged partition, $||\mathbf{P}|| = \max_{k=1,\dots,n}{\{t_k -t_{k-1}\}}$ is the 'mesh' of the partition and $t_k^* \in (t_k, t_{k+1})$ are the tags then:

$$\mathbb{E}[W_T \cdot \int_0^Tf(s)dW_s] 
= \mathbb{E}[W_T \cdot \lim_{||\mathbf{P}|| \rightarrow0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(t_k^*)(W_{t_{k+1}}-W_{t_k})]
= \lim_{||\mathbf{P}|| \rightarrow0}\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(W_{t_{k+1}}-W_{t_k}) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(t_k^*)(W_{t_{k+1}}-W_{t_k})]
= \lim_{||\mathbf{P}|| \rightarrow0}\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(t_k^*)(W_{t_{k+1}}-W_{t_k})^2]$$

This line follows from linearity of the expectation (which allows us to take expectations termwise) and the independent increments property (whereby the expectation of a product of disjoint increments is zero).

$$= \lim_{||\mathbf{P}|| \rightarrow0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(t_k^*)\mathbb{E}[(W_{t_{k+1}}-W_{t_k})^2] = \lim_{||\mathbf{P}|| \rightarrow0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(t_k^*)(t_{k+1}-t_k) = \int_0^Tf(s)ds$$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your computations appear reasonable to me, but I have one question: Why are you allowed to interchange $\mathbb{E}$ and $\lim_{\|\mathbf{P}\|\to 0}$? I guess, it is just dominated convergence, but what is the integrable bound needed for application of this theorem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I understand that in almost all applications you can take the limit outside the integral. However, I do wish I had a more rigorous knowledge of this point, and you may be able to find examples where my proof breaks down.